# I think this two divs shoule be the same height, but they aren't

Tags: css

The following code snippet shows that the height of **black** area is 4 pixels higher than the **red** one.My question is what makes this difference? I thought the image size is the same as `#placeholder`, which should make the **black** area as high as the **red** one.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header-container {
    background-color: black;
}

#header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    color: white;
}

#header-container2 {
    background-color: red;
}

#header2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
}

#placeholder {
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-container">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x80">height: 84px
    </div>
</div>
<div id="header-container2">
    <div id="header2">
        <div id="placeholder">height: 80px<div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are inline elements and default their `vertical-align` to `baseline`. Just add a style for `img` making it `vertical-align: top` or `vertical-align: middle`.

Alternatively, remove the text from beside the image and make it `display: block`.

```css
* {  margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#header-container { background-color: black; }
#header { margin: 0 auto; width: 500px; color: white; }
#header-container2 { background-color: red; }
#header2 { margin: 0 auto; width: 500px; }
#placeholder { width: 250px; height: 80px; }


img { vertical-align: top; } /* <-- Add this style to image */
```

```html
<div id="header-container">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x80">height: 84px
    </div>
</div>
<div id="header-container2">
    <div id="header2">
        <div id="placeholder">height: 80px<div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `style="display: block;"` to your top header `<img>`. This will fix your issue. It is currently using `style="display: inline;"` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Default line-height combined with image adding the extra pixel. 
check this : -http://jsbin.com/rodamapezo/1/edit?html,css,output